# When to merge a branch to the master

Tags: android, git, android-studio, merge, bitbucket

I'm new to the whole git process.  So please excuse what is a likely a simpleton question.  I use Bitbucket.  Here is what I have accomplished so far.

1) Pushed my app to bitbucket several times (master).

2) Published my app on Google Play.

3) Added some features to the app.  Created a branch.  Pushed several times. (to branch) Debugged code.  All is working swell.

4) Published new version of app to Google Play.

So I have a simple tree.  Master with a single branch.  Now what?  I would guess I would merge the branch to the master.  Yes?  No?  Would I sync anything?  Most of the tutorials assume the user has a rudimentary knowledge of the git process.  I do not have such knowledge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the workflow should look like:

1. When you are ready to create a new feature(s), create a new branch. Make it something descriptive as well. Code all of these features to the branch, and when it's done, test / debug it
2. Once testing / debugging is done, merge all of your changes into the master branch
3. Look at the code changes that was done (bitbucket should provide you with a way to see the code changes), just in case you might of missed something
4. Then publish your master branch to Google Play

Make sure to never commit anything directly to the master branch - that should only be done when merging other branches into it. It should be protected so unnecessary changes or bugs don't go into it.

Answer (score 2):

the **master** branch is a branch that is **ready** to be uploaded to google play.

as long as your app is not ready to be on google play, you keep developing on another branch, **develop**, and when you done, you merge the **develop** branch into **master** and than upload the **master** branch to google play.

your master should be perfect with no errors, the most stable version for your app